# SOQL done right. SOQL-Injection secure

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, escape, soql-injection

I was looking for some reassurance that all that needs to be done (and its best practice) when doing dynamic SOQL is to use `escapeSingleQuotes`.

There was a query like this

```
string query = 'SELECT ' + string.join(fieldsToQuery, ',') + ' FROM Custom__c where id = \'' + custom.id + '\' limit 1';
Custom__c[] customObject = Database.query(query);
```

And I changed it to this

```
String query =  'SELECT ' + String.join(fieldsToQuery, ', ') + 
                ' FROM Custom__c ' +
                ' WHERE Id = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(custom.Id) + '\'' +
                ' limit 1';
List<Custom__c> customObject = Database.query(query);
```

Will this take care of SQL Injection security problem? Or is there anything else I can do?

UPDATE

I was wondering if there is any security risk when using static queries as follows:

```
 List<Custom__c> query = [ SELECT Field__c From Custom__c 
                           WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') 
                           AND Field_c != NULL  ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`escapeSingleQuotes` works pretty well in preventing SOQL injection.  One other thing that I would look to do is to remove any places where the escape attribute is set to false on any input tags in VF.

So look for any VF tags that include `escape="false"`

From the [Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

> Be aware that setting this value to "false" may be a security risk
>   because it allows arbitrary content, including JavaScript, that could
>   be used in a malicious manner.

Just something else yopu might want to check for in conjunction with `escapeSingleQuotes`

> EDIT

To adress your editing second part of the question.  Its similar in that a user could put URL encoded injection code into the URL and you would be vulnerable.  I would instead do something like this

```
string paramID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
string query = 'SELECT Field__c From Custom__c WHERE Id = ' +
                                   '\'' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(paramID) + '\'';
List<Custom__c> customObject = Database.query(query);
```

Now you are grabbing the param value from the page, storing it, and still using the escapeSingleQuotes method.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind checking my update regarding static queries?

Comment: Just updated the answer for that scenario.

Comment: Actually, if you perform a bind as in the second query, escaping is done automatically.

Comment: Did not know that, so that would make the second escaping overkill...the more you know....

Comment: FYI, escape='false' has absolutely nothing to do with either apex or SOQL queries. Please do not confuse escape='false', which controls whether visualforce components html encode their output, with escapeSingleQuotes, which is an Apex function that performs SQL (not HTML) escaping of strings.

Comment: No confusion at all.  I know they are not related, I said it is something that you can use in **conjunction** with each other, in no way saying they are similar.